# Ubuntu 9.10: Which package can handle NTFS Junction?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-9.10, ntfs, junction

I've created some directory Junction in Windows XP

When I tried to rename those in Ubuntu 9.10, I get error message, kind of `Operation not supported`

Which Ubuntu package can handle NTFS Junction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default NTFS handler package installed in Ubuntu 9.10 is 'ntfs-3g'.
But for handling 'NTFS junction points' as 'Linux symbolic links' and manipulating them you'll need ntfs-3g-advanced package which is unfortunately not an stable release so it is not provided in Ubuntu package repository. But you can get the source and use it here:

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

There is NTFS-Config that can handle this. Take a look at the site here:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/widows-ntfs-partitions-readwrite-support-made-easy-in-ubuntu-feisty.html

Hope this will help you!